# Chart JS how to display an array of data objects as bar chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I want to display a bar chart - each bar is a user/student. And for each student, there will be an xAxis label displaying the students name

The below code is a VueJS computed property and called chartData

My data array for the bar chart is an array of objects. Here is how i generate it

```js
let dataRow = this.responses.map((d) => {
  return {
    label: d.user.name,
    data: [d.grade],
  }
});
```

Here is how I generate my labels

```js
let users = [];
this.responses.map((d) => {
  users.push(d.user.name)
});
```

I then return on object with an array of labels and datasets with data being an array of objects

```js
return {
  labels: users,
  datasets: [{
    data: dataRow
  }],
}
```

Here is how I render the chart:

```js
{
  extends: Bar,
  props: ["chartdata"],
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              max: 100
            }
          }],
        },
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
}
```

**Issue:** Nothing displays and there are no errors

The bar chart only seems to work when the data in the datasets is not an array of object like:

```js
testData: {
  labels: ['test', 'test', 'test'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [65, 59, 80],
  }]
}
```

**After Sayf-Eddine comment, i have managed to achieve this:**

[image]

**I changed how i returned the chartdata like:**

```
return {
      labels: users,
      datasets: dataRow
}
```

**However, all bars are mapping to the first label**

Comment: I think you can use directly data and not datasets array object

`return {
  labels: users,
  data: dataRow
}
`

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine I tried that but it didnt change anything. However, i did try this:

`return {
            labels: users,
            datasets: dataRow
  }`

and the bars in the chart displayed, but not across all labels

The labels rendered, but all bars seemed to map the first label in the array

Comment: Try to use  `chart.js 2.7.1` and `vue-chartjs 3.5.1`. Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-liskov-ms9rt7

Comment: @VitaliyRayets i checked out that codesandbox and figured out what was wrong with my code. when i return the data row object for a bar, im doing: 

`return {
    label: d.user.name,
    data: [d.grade],
  }`
. I changed the property data to y and it worked:
`
return {
    label: d.user.name,
    y: [d.grade],
  }
`

Answer (score 1):

**After Vitaliy Rayets comment i figured out what was wrong**

i needed to return the data row like:

```
let dataRow = this.responses.map((d) => {
  return {
    label: d.user.name,
    y: [d.grade],
  }
});
```

**I changed the property 'data' to 'y' **

Comment: You can also use parsing for your custom properties https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties